# Does Calcium Chloride remove bad smells?

Tags: consumer-products, natural-remedies, chlorine

[This advert for Thirsty Hippo Basic Tub](http://www.oxy.co.kr/eng/product/hama/ha_sub01.asp) claims it is:

> composed of calcium chloride maintains living conditions pleasant by eliminating moisture and bad smells of the air from a closet, wardrobe, vehicle, stereo-case,etc

Will it eliminate moisture and bad smells of the air?

Answer (score 1):

Calcium chloride is a desiccant (moisture absorbent) and will, to a degree, control odors due high humidity.

> Calcium chloride, CaCl2, is a common salt and the compound of calcium
>   and chlorine. It behaves as a typical ionic halide, and is solid at
>   room temperature. It has several common applications such as brine for
>   refrigeration plants, for use in concrete, as well as for ice and dust
>   control on roads. The anhydrous salt is also widely used as a
>   desiccant, where it will adsorb so much water that it will eventually
>   dissolve in its own crystal lattice water. It can be produced directly
>   from limestone, but large amounts are also produced as a by-product of
>   the Solvay process. Because of its hygroscopic nature, the anhydrous
>   form must be kept in tightly-sealed containers.
>
> Calcium chloride aggressively absorbs moisture from the air, first
>   causing a swelling of the crystals. If the air is humid enough and the
>   temperature is high enough, the crystals melt and liquid saline
>   solution brine is formed.
>
> Calcium chloride desiccants work well over a temperature range from
>   freezing up to 80°C or more. At low temperature the salt does not
>   absorb moisture under dry conditions. In practical terms calcium
>   chloride desiccants are effective at relative humidity above 30%,
>   while being more effective under moist conditions.

http://www.absortech.com/calcium-chloride-characteristics